# Need dependency tree for a Java source file

Tags: java, eclipse, dependencies

I need to extract some specific functionality from a large legacy Java codebase, in order to turn it into a standlone command-line application.  This code is not documented at all and is not very modular or even clear.  So I'm having a really hard time figuring out what I need to keep.

Basically what I need is a a dependency tree, listing all the direct or indirect dependencies of this one *.java file.  (Preferably I would like this listing to be in a format that I can save to a text file, as opposed to some un-copy-able whiz-bang GUI tree with a bazillion collapsed nodes...)

I'm using Eclipse for this detective work.  I am an Eclipse beginner, but I figure that there may be Eclipse tricks/tools to perform this kind of operation with a bit less effort.

Any suggestions (using Eclipse or otherwise) would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a free version of eUML2: http://www.soyatec.com/euml2/features/eDepend/, one of its features is exactly what you need. Also [another](http://www.dependency-analyzer.org/) one, i'm not sure if eUML can export any text files.

[Here](http://stylishtoupee.blogspot.com/2011/02/how-to-install-euml2-free-edition.html) is a kind of detailed guide installing eUML2.

Answer (score 2):

I've used [Dependency Finder](http://depfind.sourceforge.net/) for this kind of work recently and it works well.

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of the Java doc generation functionality to be able to generate a java doc that in this case will not contain much information about the methods but will give you an idea of which classes extend which classes, interfaces and such, resulting in a sort of a dependency tree.